# Generating a model in dbt with a connection to bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

I am trying to generate a model for a table which I am connecting to in bigquery.
Once I click generate model, I'm expecting that dbt picks up the table and populates the columns from big query but it's come up empty.
The below is what I get

```
with 

source as (

    select * from {{ source('staging', 'green_tripdata') }}

),

renamed as (

    select

    from source

)

select * from renamed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was as a result of not properly defining the table name. It is also helpful to look at the logs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).